# Ladda UI is not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i m facing an issue while using Laddaui for loading indicators in modal dialog 
where as if i use LADDA ui on page then it works fine.

```
<button type="button" data-ui-ladda="login.loading"
                        class="button-black2 segoe-ui-light ladda-button" data-style="expand-right"
                         ng-click="authenticate()">
                        <span class="ladda-label">LOGIN</span>
                    </button>
```

it works fine [image]. 
but if i use in angular ui modal dialog

```
 $modal.open({
            template: '<div><button type="button" data-ui-ladda="loading"  class="button-black2 segoe-ui-light ladda-button" data-style="expand-right"    ng-click="ok()">     <span class="ladda-label">Button</span>   </button> </div>',
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

                $scope.ok = function () {
                    $scope.loading = true;

                }
            },
```

it doesnt work. [image]
spinner is rotating but i think radius doesn't get set . any one have idea why this happen ? and how can i solve it ?

any help will be appreciated 
Regards

**Plunker** : http://plnkr.co/edit/HnIiqGMf8RPg47PNPslq?p=preview

Comment: What is `login.loading` in the top example, and `loading` in the bottom example?

Comment: upper loading is with different controller where as bottom loading is defined in modal controller its just to make loading true so it can be shown

Comment: are you able to setup a fiddle?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/HnIiqGMf8RPg47PNPslq?p=preview here is plunker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that Ladda is calculating the height of the button before it is being displayed, which results in the radius being 0 in length. To fix this you simply need to  wrap your link function directive content in a `$timeout`.

You need to do this when using most third party directives that require visual calculations. It ensures the element acted on is indeed rendered and visible before doing any related logic.

For example, this would now be your directive (from the plunk):

```
mymodule.directive('uiLadda', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function(){
                var Ladda = window.Ladda, ladda = Ladda.create(element[0]);
                scope.$watch(attrs.uiLadda, function(newVal, oldVal){
                    if (angular.isNumber(oldVal)) {
                        if (angular.isNumber(newVal)) {
                            ladda.setProgress(newVal);
                        } else {
                            newVal && ladda.setProgress(0) || ladda.stop();
                        }
                    } else {
                        newVal && ladda.start() || ladda.stop();
                    }
                });
            }, 0);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just add `data-spinner-size` attribute in your modal ladda button. Please see below:

```
$modal.open({
            template: '<div><button type="button" data-ui-ladda="loading"  class="button-black2 segoe-ui-light ladda-button" data-style="expand-right" data-spinner-size="35"   ng-click="ok()">     <span class="ladda-label">Button</span>   </button> </div>',
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

                $scope.ok = function () {
                    $scope.loading = true;

                }
            },
```

Comment: This did the trick for me!  Thanks for referencing this, totally overlooked it in the docs.